# Keep sprite on top and in view of screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I have a sprite that the `OrthographicCamera` follows. I have a border, that comes into the screens view when the sprite comes close to it, obviously using the `OrthographicCamera`.

My code for this is:

```
float minCameraX = camera.zoom * (camera.viewportWidth / 2)-55; 
    float maxCameraX = stageWidthHeight.x - minCameraX-80;
    float minCameraY = camera.zoom * (camera.viewportHeight / 2)-200;
    float maxCameraY = stageWidthHeight.y - minCameraY-250;     
    // set the camera to either the player or the min/max of the camera based on player position
    camera.position.set(
            Math.min(maxCameraX, Math.max(playerSprite.getX(), minCameraX)),
            Math.min(maxCameraY, Math.max(playerSprite.getY(), minCameraY)),
            0);

    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    camera.update();
```

I also have another texture/sprite (scoreboard) that I want to always have at the bottom of the user's view, and on top of everything.

How would I go about doing this?

Here are some images for what I want to achieve.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution xD

I just rendered my "scoreboard" in a different `SpriteBatch`

The suggestions on the right gave me an idea of what to search for.

I LOVE YOU STACKOVERFLOW!!

Sorry, I should have searched more.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you should use libgdx's Stage classes and scene2D.

Basically, you can easily create  different instances of the `Stage` class and add objects to the different stages.

For games I have written, I usually use a "scene" Stage, a "hud" Stage as well as Stage for Dialogs, PauseDialog etc...
Each of the Stages can have a different coordinate system and viewport and you will never have to worry about losing something from the screen.

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: Yeah, I am going to use a `Stage` for this Scoreboard too, thanks =]